# MessageBox with Yes No Cancel Button

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm()
    {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="font-size: medium; font-weight: 700; font-style: italic" Text="Submit" onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="Confirm()" />
```

i am using this script but when click on Button1, it does not check RequiredFieldValidator.
please correct my code.

Comment: see here http://www.aspsnippets.com/Green/Articles/Server-Side-Code-Behind-Yes-No-Confirmation-Message-Box-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: you can't. JavaScript does not allow such modifications in the default implementation of dialogs. the only way would be to create a custom modal dialog. you can have OK and cancel, which is a confirm() function but for other custom buttons ... unfortunately not

Comment: @Ahmedilyas what we use for yes no cancel button

Comment: as I said, there is no way of doing so unless you create your own custom modal dialog to do this.

Comment: @Rahul i edit my code please check

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you if you are using a web page. Instead of writing script in the label, you can use Clientscript like this :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "script", "confirm('" + MessageToDisplay + "');", true);
```